# Is there a word or phrase for "an attempt at parodying x that just results in x"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If not that, then just a word for a bad parody.

Inspired by this video: http://youtu.be/CPLPn4LkiN8?t=5m48s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Travesty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/travesty)*:

> NOUN
>
> A false, absurd, or distorted representation of something:

It actually helps that *travesty* is part of an alternate definition of [*parody*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parody);

> An imitation or version of something that falls far short of the real
>   thing; a ***travesty***:

A bad *parody* falls short of its *parody* genre, and simply becomes a cheep imitation of the original thing it tried to *parody*. That puts two counts of *travesty* on the docket.

It is also interesting that travesty is *[rooted](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Travesty&searchmode=none)* in ***overdressing***:

> travesty (n.) 1670s, "literary burlesque of a serious work,"
>
> from adjective meaning "dressed so as to be made ridiculous, parodied,
>   burlesqued" (1660s),
>
> from French travesti "dressed in disguise," past participle of
>   travestir "to disguise" (1590s),
>
> from Italian travestire "to disguise," from Latin trans- "over" (see
>   trans-) + vestire "to clothe" (see wear (v.)).

Of course, overdressing didn't happen in the movie, but at least the review featured the Easter Bunny at strategic moments. What the review failed to mention was that the sole purpose of the movie was to tweak tits and brandish booties, which it achieved with pornographic perfection.

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com

www.etymonline.com

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy of imitative form.  (Whoops, that's four words.)

Comment: That's fine. I said "a word or phrase".